# What do "completely described" and "complete formalisation" mean?

Tags: logic, foundations, formal-systems

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_system)

> In mathematics, an axiomatic system is any set of axioms from which
> some or all axioms can be used in conjunction to logically derive
> theorems. A mathematical theory consists of an axiomatic system and
> all its derived theorems.
>
> An axiomatic system that is **completely
> described** is a special kind of formal system; usually though, the
> effort towards **complete formalisation** brings diminishing returns in
> certainty, and a lack of readability for humans.

What do "completely described" and "complete formalisation" mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a *mathematical logic* textbook, like George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey [Computability and Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521701465) (5th ed - 2007); you will find versions of "formalized" arithmetic [see page 214-on] : usually [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) ($\sf PA$) or some subset of it, like [Robinson arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic).

Those system are completely formalized because they are based on the syntax and proof system of *first-order* logic, i.e.

- the language of the system is specified : rules for *terms* and *formulae* formation
- a complete list of logical axioms and rules of inference
- a rigorous definition of what means to be *derivable* in the system, i.e. a definition of *theorem*
- an "explicit" list of non-logical axioms (the f-o version of Peano axioms).

Having done this, we are able - in principle - the check in a "mechanical" way :

- if a string of symbols is a (well-formed) *term* or *formula* of the system
- if a *formula* is an (instance of an) axiom (logical or not) of the system
- if a sequence of *formulae* is a *derivation*, in which case the last formula of the sequence is a *theorem*.

But, and this is the real value of this approach, we can study the system itself mathematically; i.e. we can prove relevant "facts" about the system, "doing" [metamathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics) : *consistency*, *completeness*, relation with weaker and stronger systems, and so on...

Comment: Thanks. I am also wondering what the axioms, inference rules, and semantics of a lambda calculus are. I don't find it in Boolos' book. Do I miss it or is there some other references for that?

Comment: @Tim - correct; $\lambda$ is not treated in BBJ. You have to look at : Hendrik Pieter Barendregt, [The Lambda Calculus Its Syntax and Semantics](http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Semantics-Studies-Foundations-Mathematics/dp/0444875085/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1405525852&sr=1-2&keywords=Barendregt+The+Lambda+Calculus+Its+Syntax+and+Semantics) (rev ed - 1984) or Henk Barendregt & Wil Dekkers, [Lambda Calculus with Types](http://www.amazon.com/Lambda-Calculus-Types-Perspectives-Logic/dp/0521766141/ref=pd_sim_sbs_b_6?ie=UTF8&refRID=0V5WSA8BF75QJ970HYA7) (2013). 1/2